# Accessing private Dictionary

Tags: c#

We have a class with a dictionary that's public:

```
public class SomethingWithADictionary {
    public Dictionary<string, Instance> Instances { get; set; } 
}
```

Currently we access this dictionary directly, like this:

```
Instance inst = a.Instances["key"];
```

We want to make the dictionary private, but have a public way to get to the dictionary elements using the same indexer syntax. The reason is, if the instance is not in the dictionary, we'd like to take some action instead of just throwing an error.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be *exactly* the same syntax? If you don't mind accessing it as:

```
Instance inst = a["key"];
```

then it's easy - you just add an indexer:

```
public class SomethingWithADictionary {
    private Dictionary<string, Instance> instances = 
        new Dictionary<string, Instance>();

    public Instance this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            Instance instance;
            if (!instances.TryGetValue(key, out instance))
            {
                // Custom logic here
            }
            return instance;
        }
        // You may not even want this...
        set { instances[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That syntax is nicer.  I can change the callers.

Comment: Is TryGetValue slower though?  We do this a lot.  Inside the getter, would it be better to just get it the normal way and catch any exception?  The overhead of dealing with the exceptions is not an issue - these will be extremely rare.

Comment: @OldMan: Why would you expect it to be slower? It's definitely going to be faster than catching an exception in the exceptional cases, and it will also be faster than checking with ContainsKey and then using the indexer. I would expect the performance to be pretty much exactly the same as the indexer - indeed, I wouldn't be at all surprised if the indexer were implemented using TryGetValue. Of course, if you have any performance concerns, then the right approach is to *test*.

Answer (score 0):

[Indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229061.aspx) is the way to go.
This should do it:

```
public class SomethingWithADictionary {
    private Dictionary<string, Instance> Instances { get; set; } 
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerNameAttribute("Instances")]
    public  Instance this [String skillId]{
      // Add getters and setters to manipulate Instances dictionary 
    }
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't use the IndexerNameAttribute, so that still wouldn't allow it to be accessed as `a.Instances["foo"]` with C#. You've also left the field public, and that won't even compile at the moment, as you've got two members names "Instances".

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, just edited my code. Who is using `IndexerNameAttribute` then? Any idea of why it is still available even not used by the compiler?